# c++ Reading a file into a vector of objects, then copying to vector pointer

Tags: c++, vector

I am writing a program to read from a file and take each line into an object and have all the contents of that line separated into their own variables in that object. I got that part down, it's just that the functions that have been defined for me are like so

```
void printSpecs(vector<watercraft *> inventory).
```

Can you help me take the input from the file into a vector of objects, then pass that vector into a function like the one above?

Here is what I have so far but it is not right.

```
    vector <watercraft *> test;
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("watercraft.txt", ios::in);
if(!inFile){
    cout << "Something wrong with input file" << endl;
    exit(0);
}                    
                for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++){
                    watercraft tempPtr(inFile);
                    test.push_back(&tempPtr);
                }
```

It results in this

```
1: pontoon  Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
2: pontoon  Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
3: pontoon  Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
4: pontoon  Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
5: pontoon  Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
6: pontoon  Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
7: pontoon  Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
8: pontoon  Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
9: pontoon  Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
10: pontoon Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
11: pontoon Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
12: pontoon Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
13: pontoon Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
14: pontoon Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
15: pontoon Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
16: pontoon Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
17: pontoon Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
18: pontoon Bentley 200 Cruise  Mercury 90  Silver  20  37795
```

All the same line which is actually the last line of the file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tempPtr` is local to its scope and is invalidated at the end of its scope. Therefore, storing its pointer and dereferencing the pointer later is dangerous.

For example, you can create objects on heap so that they won't be deleted by exiting scope.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++){
    test.push_back(new watercraft(inFile));
}
```

Another option is creating a vector of `watercraft`, then adding pointers to each elements. (Don't add elements while creating the vector because re-allocation may invalidate existing pointers):

```
vector<watercraft> watercrafts;

for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++){
    watercraft tempPtr(inFile);
    watercrafts.push_back(tempPtr);
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < watercrafts.size(); i++){
    test.push_back(&watercrafts[i]);
}
```